# How to create a program i n Java which gets all combinations of 1 and 2 of given number of digits

Tags: java, algorithm

Let's say n= 7, so I need to display all possible combinations of 7 digits made out of 1s and 2s: 
1111111
1111112
1111121
1111211
1112111
.......
2222222
Here is my code, but it is hardcoded nested 7 times loops. So my count=128 which is 2^7 But how to make it programmatically for n number of times nesting? I think it needs some recursion, but how to do it?

```
int count = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j<=2; j++) {
        for (int z= 1; z<=2; z++) {
            for (int i = 1; i<=2; i++) {
                for (int k = 1; k<=2; k++) {
                    for (int l= 1; l<=2; l++) {
                        for (int m = 1; m<=2; m++) {
                            for (int y = 1; y<=2; y++) {
                                count++;

                                System.out.println(count+":"+j+z+i+k+l+m+y+",");

                            }
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you need is backtracking

Comment: Holy mother of nests...

Answer (score 5):

Usually, "all combinations of N symbols" is the same than "counting in base N".

Since you have two symbols, even easier. Count from 0 to `X`, get the binary representation of each number, replace `0` by `2`. Once the binary representation gets longer than the number of values you desire, stop.

Do not forget to add leading `2` to numbers which are too short.

Comment: I was going to suggest a base variable and an array of digits which you increment with a `next` function but this is much simpler :o

Comment: I have to admit that it is dirty and slow, though... good for a beginner's exercise but would not put that in production code.

Comment: rolfl's answer is the "refined" version of my algorithm (does the operation with the binary expression instead of its String representation). I like it better, too.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like an obfuscated version .... ;-) :

```
    final int l = 7;
    long m = 1 << l;
    while (--m >= 0) {
        int b=l;
        while (--b >= 0) {
            System.out.print(((m >> b)& 1 ) + 1);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

Edit:
I should add a description of the above.... All I do is count down from `2^7 - 1` and then print the bits set in each value (printing `2` for bit-value 1, and printing `1` for bit-value 0);

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion. You should plan to pass in the partially-built string, and the number of digits remaining. I will concatenate strings here, though StringBuilders should generally be used.

```
public static void printOutString(int levelsRemaining, String current){
    if(levelsRemaining==0) System.out.println(current);
    else{
        printOutString(levelsRemaining-1, current+"1");
        printOutString(levelsRemaining-1, current+"2");
    }
}
```

You can also use an iterative approach:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAllStrings(int length){
    ArrayList<String> prev;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        ArrayList<String> newL=new ArrayList<String>;
        for(String s:prev){
            newL.add(s+"1");
            newL.add(s+"2");
        }
        prev=newL;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Comment: The 1st example works, but the 2nd doesn't. Still thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to get all permutations of some domain, ie you would calling:
`permute(3,"12", "");` yields:

> 111 112 121 122 211 212 221 222

```
public void permute(int length, String domain, String result)
    {
        if (length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < domain.length(); i++)
                permute(length-1, domain, result + domain.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user2977438 Not sure what you mean by that.  If you're never to want a different domain, then you can just take it out as one of the parameters and simply declare it in the function.  You can easily turn this into two methods, one that can be called by a user with minimal input, which can call this method.  It's easy to modify...